# Suggestion for Calendar of Events Plugin

Tags: calendar

I am searching for a plugin with the following properties, any suggestions would be appreciated:

- All events should able to be organised either by date or subject, searchable by visiting users
  and should include the capability to auto-expire.
- Each event should include a general description, venue details (date / time / area etc) and related images or videos.
- Users must be able to subscribe to an email notification mechanism which informs them about upcoming events.
- Calendar must also provide an approval workflow process prior the publishing of an event.

Comment: sorry didn't know I had to click that button :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll give various types of calendar's, you choose any one of them as your needs.
[Sample Calendar](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/wordpress/best-calendar-plugins-wordpress/). I think some combination is too good. :)